# How to upload pdf or, docs in safari or any popular browser in iOS?

Tags: ios, safari, pdf, document-management

I was just stunned today, when I just discovered that I cannot upload my resume either in pdf/doc while applying for a job.

All I have access to is Photos, which is my photos and videos repository.

Is there actually a way to upload documents in safari or it is just not allowed in iPhones or iOS.

Answer (score 6):

Yah, mobile Safari does not support file uploading, even via a web upload form... sigh. However there are a number of ways to upload from an IOS device. here are two:

1. Dropbox, this has the benefit of having access to a large number of files and is free for most, depending on how many files you have. But you cant upload to web forms directly from Dropbox.
2. iCab, I've used this browser for a couple of years for just the reason you indicate. It allows you to upload (and download) files. I have not needed to do it for a while so I am not sure about the source for the files to be uploaded but I am pretty sure it includes Dropbox. It's not free but only a couple of bucks and well worth it.

Comment: Is there any Apple's official documentation about not supporting file upload? I tested and mobile safari behaves exactly like you said. But I would like to be able find a link to an official source.

Comment: I am not aware of anything like that, though there may be documents I don't have access to if I was a registered developer... might be in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Using the normal "choose file" buttons found on most webpages, no. Unfortunately, on iOS, that button really means "choose photos". I think some websites let you upload a file from Dropbox, which is the only workaround I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefox this browser allows PDFs to be uploaded to Web Forms

Comment: This is true for iOS 11 as it uses File Manager.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a bug at the moment i Safari for iOS as of september 2019, that prevent users from uploading pdf files unless accepting all types of files:

```
<input type="file" accept="*" />
```

Normally you would specify that pdf is accepted like this:

```
<input type="file" accept="application/pdf" />
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on how to actually use what you're suggesting? Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.

Comment: Also, I don't think changing the HTML code is possible in the scenario the OP was facing (primarily being unable to pick a document to attach/upload in the iOS version  of 2015)

Comment: This actually solved it for me. Thanks